# Trying to add a Tableview inside of a UIView. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I'm not sure how to approach this. I'm loading a separate table view controller nib file to my viewcontroller. How do I position it the way I want? Also, Is the below query all I need, or am I missing something? It keeps crashing on me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    HSTableViewController *tableViews = [[HSTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HSTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:tableViews];
    tableViews.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    //tableViews.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:tableViews.view];
    [tableViews didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: What's the output? Nothing shows up? You will also have to add a `delegate` and `dataSource`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone else needs this. See this tutorial I found on youtube that helped a lot. Thanks for all the help.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzedmcFlm1c

Comment: Link only answers are not very useful if the link goes away. Please try to add the relevant information to the answer itself.

Comment: The video was useful because it showed how to link the File's Owner outlet properly

Answer (score 2):

To add a tableview in code to a view controller wherein that VC will act as both the data source and delegate you would do the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
  }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello World";

    return cell;
}
```

And then in your .H file you need to inform the program that you're going to act as both the Delegate and DataSource

```
@interface NSSViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

From what I gathered out of your question, that should get you where you need to go. I will edit accordingly if you require further assistance.

Comment: I would like to add a tableViewController as a subview of my UIview..My data and delegate will be coming from a different controller. I figured I needed to add it as a ChildViewController.

Comment: Is the tableview not going to take up the full screen? You can still make self the datasource then instantiate the model with the data in the vc.

Comment: Peter that sounds like  it may be my best bet...I'll give it a try and get back to you. THanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Set your `UITableView`'s frame in `-viewWillAppear:` like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    tableViews.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```